Does the manifold bounday equation $\partial W=M$ has at most 1 solution?
Are there two non homeomorphic compact smooth manifolds $W_1,W_2$ such that their boundaries are diffeomorphic manifolds? Is there an example of this situation such that the boundary is a parallelizable manifold or even a Lie group?

Your title and the  body of the question lead to contradictory answers. :)

@TedShifrin what  is tge contradiction? BTW please see my comment on your answer

@TedShifrin Yes you are  right. Now  I realize  what do you mean:  Any possible  "Yes"  or  "No"  answer would  be  a  contradiction :)  BTW what  about  my comment  to  your  answer?

Of course. Take a $g$-holed torus $M$ and remove a ball $B$ from it. Then $\partial\bar B = -\partial (M-B)$, but $\bar B$ and $M-B$ are far from homeomorphic. This generalizes to any dimension, so you can get, for example, $S^3$ as the common boundary.

Thank you!what about contractible W?  I think all Milnor spheres are boundary if smooth B_8.But the boundqries are nit diffeomorphic. So does my question has an obvious answer if we requiere W_1 and W_2 would be contrqctible?
